# Concatenating strings with spaces in Perl. Any built-ins?

Tags: perl

In Perl I can concatenate multiple strings with spaces between them as follows:

```
my $long_string = $one_string . " " . $another_string . " " . $yet_another_string . " " . 
$and_another_string . " " $the_lastr_string
```

However, typing this is a bit cumbersome.

Is there a built-in that can make this task easier?

e.g. something like:

```
concatenate_with_spaces($one_string, $another_string, $yet_another_string, ...)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html):

```
my $x = 'X';
my @vars = ( 1, 'then', 'some' );
my $long_string = join ' ', $x, 2, @vars;   # "X 2 1 then some"
```

Answer (score 9):

Zaid has given the idiomatic solution, using `join`. However, there are more ways to do it.

```
my @vars = ($one, $two, $three);
my $str1 = "@vars";               # Using array interpolation
my $str2 = "$one $two $three";    # interpolating scalars directly
```

Interpolating an array uses the predefined variable [`$"`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%22) (*list separator*), which is by default set to space. When interpolating variables, you do not need to use `.` to concatenate spaces to your strings, they can be used directly in a double quoted string.

Answer (score 4):

```
my @list_of_strings = ($one_string, $two_strings );
my $string = join(' ', @list_of_strings );
print $string;
```

Comment: Awesome. I should have thought about that. Thanks!